# Custom Element based in props with React

Tags: reactjs

So I was wondering if can pass the element name with React to an child componenet, so for example I have this now:

```js
export default function Title({ title, style, size }) {
  switch (size) {
    case 'h1':
      return <h1 style={style}>{title}</h1>;
    case 'h2':
      return <h2 style={style}>{title}</h2>;
    case 'h3':
      return <h3 style={style}>{title}</h3>;
    case 'h4':
      return <h4 style={style}>{title}</h4>;
    case 'h5':
      return <h5 style={style}>{title}</h5>;
  }
}
```

How can I make it work like this somehow:

```
export default function Title({ title, style, size }) {
  return <size style={style}>{title}</size>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to achieve it

- The first param is your tag name like (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) or another React component
- The second param is your props like (`style={style}`)
- The third param is child components or content that you want to render along with the element

```
export default function Title({ title, size, ...props }) {
  return React.createElement(size, props, title)
}
```

Comment: For example how to structure an Element general object that can be used for all elements, for example this: `<input type="text" value="test" onChange="a fun" .../>`

Comment: I modified my answer with dynamic props for you @rehipex378. I'm considering that `title` and `size`are fixed because your component name `Title`

Comment: I mean how to collect className, style and other atributes

Comment: `...props` will consist of all your props (except `title` and `size`) you pass to `Title` component. If you want to get more attributes, you can explicitly expose them like `{ title, size, className, ...props }` @rehipex378